# How to hide with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to conditionally show/hide text fields, but hide them all initially. I have it to a point where it will work if the page is refreshed, but it initially displays all of the fields that are supposed to be hidden: http://joelmorehouse.com/soderholminsurance/get-a-quote.

I added jQuery 1.7.1 to my theme in /wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/.

I created a script named hidefieldsScript.js and put it in the js folder for my theme: http://joelmorehouse.com/soderholminsurance/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/hidefieldsScript.js.

I pasted this code at the top of the body in my header.php:

`<!-- Add jquery script to support Conditional Forms-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/1.7.1/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/hidefieldsScript.js"></script>`

And here is the HTML I'm using in Contact Form 7

```html
<div id="contactForm">
<h3>Get a Free Quote</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="your-name">Your Name<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text* your-name id:your-name class:contactForm ""]
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="insurance-type">Type of Insurance<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[select* insurance-type id:insurance-type include_blank class:contactForm "Auto Insurance" "Home Insurance" "Life Insurance" "Commercial Insurance" "Health Insurance" "Bond" "Other"]
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-auto1">
      <label for="number-of-drivers">Number of Drivers<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text number-of-drivers id:number-of-drivers class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-auto2">
      <label for="number-of-vehicles">Number of Vehicles<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text number-of-vehicles id:number-of-vehicles class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-auto3">
      <label for="currently-insured-auto">Currently Insured? (Yes/No)<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text currently-insured-auto id:currently-insured-auto class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>

<!-- HOME INSURANCE FIELDS -->

    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-home1">
      <label for="age-of-home">Age of Home<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text age-of-home /50 id:age-of-home class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-home2">
      <label for="dwelling-value">Dwelling Value<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text dwelling-value /50 id:dwelling-value class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-home3">
      <label for="owner-occupied">Owner Occupied? (Yes/No)<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text owner-occupied /50 id:owner-occupied class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-home4">
      <label for="new-purchase">New Purchase (If yes, please provide closing date.)<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text new-purchase /50 id:new-purchase class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-home5">
      <label for="currently-insured-home">Currently Insured? (Yes/No)<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text currently-insured-home /50 id:currently-insured-home class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>

<!-- LIFE INSURANCE FIELDS -->

    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-life1">
      <label for="dob-life">Date of Birth<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text dob-life /50 id:dob-life class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-life2">
      <label for="smoker-life">Smoker? (Yes/No)<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text smoker-life /50 id:smoker-life class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-life3">
      <label for="amount-desired">Amount of Insurance Desired<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text amount-desired /50 id:amount-desired class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-life4">
      <label for="currently-insured-life">Current Life Insurance Policy? (Yes/No)<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text currently-insured-life /50 id:currently-insured-life class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>

<!-- COMMERCIAL INSURANCE FIELDS -->

    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-com1">
      <label for="business-type">Type of Business<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text business-type /50 id:business-type class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-com2">
      <label for="years-in-business">Years in Business<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text years-in-business /50 id:years-in-business class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-com3">
      <label for="federal-id">Federal ID#<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text federal-id /50 id:federal-id class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-com4">
      <label for="business-description">Business Operations Description<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text business-description /50 id:business-description class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-com5">
      <label for="number-of-employees">Number of Employees<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text number-of-employees /50 id:number-of-employees class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>

<!-- HEALTH INSURANCE FIELDS -->

    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-health1">
      <label for="medicare">Medicare? (Yes/No)<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text medicare /50 id:medicare class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-health2">
      <label for="dob-health">Date of Birth<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text dob-health /50 id:dob-health class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-health3">
      <label for="smoker-health">Smoker? (Yes/No)<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text smoker-health /50 id:smoker-health class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-health4">
      <label for="deductible">Deductible<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text deductible /50 id:deductible class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>

<!-- BOND -->

    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-bond1">
      <label for="address">Address<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text address /50 id:address class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>

<!-- OTHER -->

    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-other1">
      <label for="other-types">Type(s) of Insurance<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text other-types /50 id:other-types class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hide" id="hide-other2">
      <label for="description-of-coverage">Description of Coverage<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text description-of-coverage /50 id:description-of-coverage class:contactForm ""]
       </div>
    </li>

<!-- EMAIL ADDRESS -->
    <li>
      <label for="your-email">Your Email Address<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[email* your-email /50 id:your-email class:contactForm ""]
    </li>
    <li>

<!-- PHONE -->
    <li>
      <label for="your-phone">Your Phone Number<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></label>[text* your-phone id:your-phone class:contactForm ""]
    </li>
    <li>

<!-- ADDITIONAL NOTES -->

      <label for="additional-notes" style="padding-top: .5em;">Additional Notes</label>[textarea* additional-notes id:additional-notes class:contactForm "Optional"]
    </li>
    <li>
  </ul>
<span style="color:#ff0000;">* = Required Field</span>
</div>
[submit]
```

What's going on here? I read somewhere to place the script to the body of my header.php rather than the head, so I did that without success. I also found a similar post, but their problem was invalid IDs.

Comment: I tried going to your site, and I see a few console errors - however the page just keeps refreshing so I can't read what they are in time - work on the console errors first. Also, chances are with WordPress you want to "enqueue" your scripts AND chances are it's already including jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That error of the page refreshing should be resolved (I tried adding a plugin that would refresh the page after one second, but it just kept going in a loop). I'm not sure what you mean by console errors, and enqueueing my scripts. Sorry, this is all totally new to me.

Comment: I am not that familiar with WordPress, but you say that you have put the Javascript inside the `js` folder. Why then are you using the `css` folder, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer above is good by devJunk.

Also, if someone's connection is a little slower, this is not the most efficient way to hide those form fields.  You may end up having the accordion effect where the user initially sees the field and then they see it hide - since the hide script doesn't kick in until everything in the DOM has loaded, including the other scripts.  This is why you have the $(document).ready method attached.

Instead, you should use css to hide these fields.

instead of:

```
$("#hide-auto2").hide();
```

try:

```
#hide-auto2{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble with jQuery because you're including it several times, once in the body, once in the header. When entering your site, the console shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Twice, once for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

and a second time for

```
$("#hide-auto1").hide();
```

Which means that basically jQuery is not being loaded properly. Consider including it just once, on the footer of the theme, inside the body, and from a CDN:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

This is for version 2.1.1, which doesn't support IE <9, but is the newest available.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

This is for the latest 1.x version. 1.7.1, the one you're using, is too old.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. So if you're willing to hold my hand through this process, I need to know exactly what I need to change in what files in order to fix this. Can I simply replace `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/1.7.1/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` in my header.php with `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, you can. But as I was saying, you should probably put them in the footer. The logic behind that is that thing in the footer are loaded after the rest of the things, which is considered a good practice for JS. If you decide against this, which would be fine too, you would have to delete references to the old versions and just replace them with the links I provided.

Comment: Sorry - I just saw this message. Thanks for following up on this. I ended up just removing all of the custom scripts and going with a pre-built plugin for ease of use, but this is great to know for future reference. I appreciate the help!